Change vector's basis from 3d spherical to cartesian coordinates
I am writing a simulation program.
I have a vector field in spherical coordinates which I need to transform into Cartesian coordinates.
I understand how this works in $2D$ case - simple enough, I just rotate by the angle.
But in spherical coordinates there are two angles and I can't figure out which angle I should rotate by first. I am worried about this because rotations in $3D$ are generally NOT commutative.
Note that Calculate divergence $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$ in spherical coordinates does NOT answer my question.

What exactly is your question?

How do you use spherical coordinates to describe a vector field?

@DavidK just like here :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_flow_around_a_circular_cylinder except you have two angles instead of one to describe the origin point of each vector and the vector itself has three components instead of two. One vector component stays parallel to the spherical 'arm', while two others are orthogonal.
See also a good illustration here https://stemjock.com/STEM%20Books/BSL%20Transport%20Phenomena%202e%20Revised/Chapter%204/BSLTPCh4p4B5.pdf

@KurtG. Hm... second half of it. It provides the final matrix, but i want to understand how to get to that matrix. As i wrote, i tried to create that matrix from scratch by myself by doing rotations around the axes but rotations in 3d are not commutative and i dont know how to deal with this.
The process is as important as the final result, give a man a fish and all that.

So you have at each point a vector described by the local Cartesian coordinates of the tangent space at that point. The angles of the spherical coordinates of the point tell you the orientation of the tangent space. OK.

It depends on the convention of your coordinate system. See here for more information. If you describe your convention more precisely I'd be happy to help. On the linked page there are also formulae to do the conversion.
